# Besides the seals of Rassilon, Omega, The Master, and The Time Lords, what other seals are in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

My friend and I are working on a project that requires the use of seals from the WhoVerse, particularly, those of individual Time Lords.

So far we have:

[image: Time Lord Seals]

We also have the Mark of the Corsair to work with and [this reference to the Seal of Omega](https://www.geeknative.com/18063/will-benedict-cumberbatch-play-omega-in-doctor-who/)

Do any of you know of other seals or symbols that are impactful in the WhoVerse? We are looking specifically at Time Lord Seals however we could also use seals/emblems/symbols of races, both villain and good.

Comment: Are you sure the Seal of the Master is his seal and not just his name? It looks like the writing from River Song's crib, arranged in a loop.

Comment: [The Doctor's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Doctor_calling_card.jpg)? Alternatively, [this one](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tardis/images/d/df/DA_Doctors_message.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20101030143713).

Comment: @Axelrod Yes - these are the symbols on the Masters Ring:
http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_of_the_Time_Lords_%28TV_story%29


Total side note: I just realized that the sign for Omega was featured in 'A Good Man':
http://io9.gizmodo.com/5938410/does-steven-moffat-have-a-master-plan-for-doctor-who

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Where did the second image come from? I Couldnt make it out. Its very small

Comment: @Codebunnie [The Deadly Assassin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deadly_Assassin); The Doctor's letter warning about the assassination of the president. The Seal is described as "Prydonian" in the episode. Oh, and [Theta Sigma](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHleH.jpg) is a nickname of the Doctor.

Answer (score 5):

There is, of course, the [Great Seal of Diplos](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Seal_of_Diplos), which is actually a segment of the Key to Time.

[image: Great Seal of Diplos]

Like all the segments (except the fourth), it was an item of great power.  Cessair the Diplos, the villain in "The Stones of Blood" uses is power to change her appearance, and it can also be used to command the justice machines sent from Diplos to apprehend her.

Answer (score 4):

I am aware that I'm a bit late to respond, but if you're still interested, yes, I do know of some other seals.

@ElliotFrisch mentioned Rassilon's seal being called 'Prydonian'. I have done a bit of research on Doctor Who and have found that there are six Gallifreyan chapters, or six chapters of Time Lord society. Three are academic and three are pragmatic.
The Academic Triad are the Patrex (or Patrexes) Chapter, the Arcalian Chapter, and the Dromeian chapter. The Pragmatic Triad are the Prydonian Chapter, Cerulean Chapter, and the Scendles Chapter. They each have their own seal. Each chapter had a different founder. The Prydonian Chapter was founded by Rassilon, which is why the seal is called the Prydonian seal as well as Rassilon's seal.

[image]

This is one picture of Rassilon's seal shown for all the chapters, but using their colors. Usually each of the different chapters are shown using Rassilon's seal like this, but that is because Rassilon was the President of the High Council, and so the Prydonian Chapter was then considered the most important, in a way. They do have their own seals, however. In order, Rassilon's seal, Omega's seal, Lazuline's seal, Apeiron's seal, Eutenoyar's seal, and Pandak's.

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

I've accidentally put the images of the chapter seals in the wrong order and I can't seem to fix them, so just to clarify, the names of the seals go with the order of the first picture, left to right. 
Credit goes to Rory Prisogika for creating the non-canon seals.

Answer (score 1):

The only canon seals that I know of are the Time Lord seal, Rassilon and Omega's seal, and the seal of the Master. The four founder seals other than Rassilon and Omega's were designed by myself and a former member of a fandom group I run, New Gallifrey.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted another great seal in the Third Doctor story "[The Time Monster](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Time_Monster_(TV_story))"—the Great Seal of Kronos (the titular monster).  Here it is in close-up, with the Master inspecting the markings on its surface.

[image: Great Seal of Kronos]

The seal is initially in the possession of Krasis, the high priest of the Temple of Poseidon in Atlantis.  The Master summons him from the present to learn about how to control the chronovoric monstrosity.

[image: Krasis wearing the seal]

After the Master cows Krasis and confiscates the seal, he uses it to control (or at least ward off) Kronos.

(Note that the linear style of the seal is rather reminiscent of the pocket watch from "Human Nature"/"The Family of Blood."  This may be a direct allusion by the later production team, or they merely have drawn on the same stylistic influences.)